# Add taxonomy term description to views-view-fields--taxonomy_banner.html.twig

Tags: 8, views, theming

using taxonomy term view to render my products in Drupal 8.9 with commerce 2 .
I am trying to add the term description under a banner .. but struggling to find what I need to add.

new to twig,and theming
any help appreciated.

I have added

```
<p>{{ fields.description.content }}</p>
```

```
{% set banner =  row._entity.field_banner %}
{% if fields.name %}
    <h3><strong>{{ fields.name.content }}</strong></h3>
{% endif %}
{% if banner is not empty %}
<div class="owl-carousel boxed-banner-carosel owl-theme" data-plugin-options='{"items":1}'>
    {% for value in banner %}
    <div class="boxed-banner">
        <img src="{{ file_url(value.entity.fileuri) }}" alt="Banner">
            <p>{{ fields.description.content }}</p>
    </div>
    
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

If someone could kindly explain where I am going wrong ...thanks

[image]

Comment: This does not really help in terms of the way you are doing this now, but if you were to change the views display to a view mode, create a custom view mode and render it that way, it would probably be a lot easier from a custom template / theming perspective.